# Create static library in Visual C++ Express 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++

how to create static library in Visual C++ Express 2010? When creating project, I cant find static library option. Thanks.

Comment: Does http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/libraries1.aspx help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new one:

- `New project -> Win32 Console Application -> Static Library` (the generated project will be empty)

Or configure an existing C++ project to become a static library:

- `Project property Pages -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type`, select  'Static library'

Comment: Going through Win32 Project makes more sense.

Comment: I have a quick question. If I create a C++ static library which has some dependencies on some other libraries, do I need to give my library and all dependencies to whom is going to use my code? or just the compiled static library works? (no need to deliver dependencies?)