# Can Custom Functions Be Stored In Libraries And Used On Basic Data Types / C++?

Tags: c++, function, libraries

How can i create my library (or something like that), that I can save/edit and include it in my file. It should contain functions that I created and the main thing is that I can use them on my variables, for example:

I want to create a function:

```
appendString(string additionalText) - function in "library"
```

And to have a variable:

```
string myString = "Hello " - variable in file (in which I "included" library)
```

After that, I write:

```
myString.appendString("World");
```

So, at the end `myString` should be "Hello World".

PLEASE NOTE: THESE FUNCTIONS WILL BE CALLED ON BASIC DATA TYPES, NOT OBJECTS!

Comment: @super you don't `#include` a cpp file, you add it to your project's makefile instead

Comment: Is your question "how can I make my own library?" or "how can I add new methods to an existing class?"?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487117/create-static-library-in-visual-c-express-2010, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603272/creating-c-library-with-cmake, etc. We already have a lot of answers - nothing personal Luka.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is a class type, not a "basic data type", as evident by the fact that you are calling a member method on it.  Basic types don't have methods.

You can't add new methods to an existing class type, you would have to derive a new class from it.  However, STL containers like `std::string` are not designed to be derived from (no virtual destructors, etc).

It would make more sense to implement your `appendString()` function like this <sup>1</sup>:

```
void appendString(string &text, const string &additionalText)
```

And then call it like this:

```
appendString(myString, "World");
```

<sup>1: `std::string` already has several [`append()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) methods, eg: `myString.append("World");`</sup>

In any case, to answer your question, you can write a pair of `.h`/`.cpp` files, where the `.h` file declares your custom functions and types, and the `.cpp` file implements them.

Then, you can `#include` the `.h` wherever you need it, and either

1. add the `.cpp` file to each project.
2. compile the `.cpp` into a static `.lib` file (or equivalent, depending on compiler and target platform) that you can then link into each project's final executable.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is clear and you answered really fast! I will sure try it out, because I think this is what i need! Thank you once more!